# mysqldump stuck at "Connecting to"

Tags: mysql, linux, mysqldump, ubuntu, docker

I'm having a weird problem with `mysqldump`. I have a docker instance of mysql (5.7) to which I can connect just fine (to any database). I can also use mysqldump to dump the databases except one - after executing mysqldump on that database it simply hangs on "Connecting to " and does nothing.

I use simple:

`mysqldump --routines=true -v -h <host> -u root -p<pass> <database>`

I also tried adding: `--single-transaction` or `-l` without much success.

I can connect to this database just fine (if I switch `mysqldump` to `mysql`).

I'm not really sure how to debug this issue further as there are no errors nor log entries.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so `show processlist;` revealed that some queries got stuck in "Waiting to lock metadata" on that table. `show engine innodb status \G` helped identify the offending transaction and then simple `KILL <id>` unlocked the system.